# IDA: How to iterate through the segments in a script

Tags: ida

I tried writing a simple loop which used GetSegmentAttr to get the start and end of the current segment and then assumed that the end of the current segment would be the start of the next segment, but this assumption was faulty. It worked for a few segments, but I discovered that there may be gaps between segments.

So, what I am wondering is how one can reliably iterate through all of the segments founds?

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the result of [`idautils.Segments()`](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idautils-module.html#Segments):

```
for seg in idautils.Segments():
    # ...
```

Comment: Actually, it's `idautils`, not `idaapi`.

Answer (score 2):

Use FirstSeg() and NextSeg() like so

```
#include <idc.idc>

static main() {
    auto seg;
    auto start;
    auto end; 

    seg = FirstSeg();

    while(seg != BADADDR)
    {
        start = SegStart(seg);
        end = SegEnd(seg);

        Message("Seg: %a Start: %a End: %a\n", seg, start, end);

        // do looping here

        seg = NextSeg(seg);
    }
}
```

Then loop a variable from 'start' to including 'end'

For my current project the above gives:

```
Seg: ROM:00000000 Start: ROM:00000000 End: ROM2:00880000
Seg: ROM2:00880000 Start: ROM2:00880000 End: 0:009FFFFF
Seg: CHIP:40000000 Start: CHIP:40000000 End: 0:4004FFFF
Seg: CHIP:40050000 Start: CHIP:40050000 End: 0:4005FFFF
Seg: CHIP:40070000 Start: CHIP:40070000 End: 0:4007FFFF
Seg: CHIP:40130000 Start: CHIP:40130000 End: 0:4013FFFF
Seg: CHIP:40180000 Start: CHIP:40180000 End: 0:4018FFFF
Seg: CHIP:401D0000 Start: CHIP:401D0000 End: 0:401DFFFF
Seg: CHIP:50000000 Start: CHIP:50000000 End: 0:5001FFFF
Seg: s6800:68000000 Start: s6800:68000000 End: 0:6800FFFF
Seg: CHIP:6F000000 Start: CHIP:6F000000 End: 0:6F00FFFF
Seg: RAM:8F800000 Start: RAM:8F800000 End: 0:8F9FFFFF
Seg: RAM:8FB00000 Start: RAM:8FB00000 End: 0:8FFFFFFF
Seg: RAM:CD000000 Start: RAM:CD000000 End: 0:CEFFFFFF
```